# How to debug a Javascript proxy.pac file used for IE proxy settings?

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer, proxy.pac

does someone know if its posible to debug a proxy.pac, this file is written in Javascript.
how can it be attached to some debug engine like Visual Studio or any other IDE

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is "pactester" on Google Code. Works beautifully.

- http://code.google.com/p/pactester/

**Edit:**

The tester has now been moved into the parser project:

- https://github.com/pacparser/pacparser

Answer (score 2):

[PRB: Cannot Debug a .pac File from Visual InterDev](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274356) (or "How to debug a .pac File")  could help. Working with IE 8 and Visual Studio 2008 here.